Reading Temperatures of DDR4 SDRAM memories with i2c-tools
I am trying to read the temperatures of two DDR4 SDRAMS on my motherboard via Ubuntu 22. I confirmed that there is a temperature sensor in my memories.
I can reach these memory temperatures with the HwInfo program on Windows, but the i2c-tools I use to read SPDs on Ubuntu does not work.
When I scan with i2cdetect, there is no change in the i2c addresses displayed when I remove and insert one or two of the memories. As far as I understand, my memories are not detected at all. I try to read the displayed addresses just in case. Although their labels are temperatures, it was clear that they were not memory addresses.
When i run decode-dimms the eeprom driver says the detected dimm does not exist:
“Number of SDRAM DIMMs detected and decoded: 0“
While trying it with ee1004 and at24, it returns a hardware not supported error:
“No eeprom found, the kernel probably does not support your hardware.”
Can anyone give me an idea on how can I  read temperatures?

I do not see a question here. There simply is no support in the tools you are using to do what you are trying to do.It is not clear what it is you are asking.

@DavidDE according to the documents I have reached, the method I have applied is correct. Other people have access to memory temperature with this tool. The tool and the drivers I mentioned are developed to read the SPD values, but for some reason they don't work on my system. I wanted to get an idea about this.

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! What version of Ubuntu are you running? Please run lsb_release -a and Edit your question to include this information.
